# Controlling android camera with computer

Tags: android, python, c++, linux, bash

I want to be able to run a program on my desktop (C++, bash, or python would all be preferred. I have plenty of experience with those languages so no worries there) to control the camera on my android phone. (While the phone is connected to my computer via USB.)

I'm guessing I should start by looking through the android SDK docs, but not sure if that's even the place to start, because I'm assuming the SDK is to write programs for the phone itself, not writing programs to control the phone.

The only functions I need are record, stop, set zoom level, and set save filename.

Basically my question is: where should I start looking, and if you have heard of a tutorial or example that shows an easy way to do something like this, I would appreciate it.

I have a Galaxy S5, and my desktop runs Debian 8.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure this is possible without also having an app on the phone that does all the work. The app on you computer talks to the app on phone that does all the work. A simple Google search may yeild possible avenues of interest, such as http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2786395

Comment: I figured the app on the phone that does the work would be the standard "camera" app. Thanks!

Comment: No, you would need to create your own camera app that would connect to the desktop app. The phone app would take commands from the desktop app. Any standard camera app can't do that natively.

Comment: Ah gotcha! I was thinking maybe the camera app already has an API to allow control.

Comment: It's been a while, but I'm pretty sure that Python via SL4a provides camera/media 'facades' that might work for simple needs.  :)